# Will pointers in a object created using deep copy point the objects in the original object

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, deep-copy

Say i have this class:

```
class Entity
{
private:
    std::vector<Component*> _components;
public
    Entity(std::vector<Component*>);
};
```

And i do this:

```
Entity* entity= new Entity( { new Drawable(), new Transform() ... } );
Entity* clone = new Entity(*entity);
```

Will the objects that the pointers in _components point to get copied? Or are only the pointers getting copied to clone?

Comment: Only the pointers in `_components` will be copied. You should follow the rule of three (or five) for your class to manage the memory correctly, see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: Pointers are getting copied, not objects pointed to. Write a custom copy constructor.

Comment: I feel you don't really know when to use pointers and when not to. do you come from a Java/C# background?

Comment: I am a student so i dont really have much of a background, the context that the components are used require them to be pointers, but i will review my design again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the objects that the pointers in `_components` point to get copied?

No.

> Or are only the pointers getting copied to clone?

Yes.